# Adding a toggle on/off switch to rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change a select tag to a js toggle on/off switch in my rails app.

I found a nice simple one on w3schools

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_select_switch

I added this to my application.js :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then added this script to my view :

```
<label for="switch">Toggle Switch:</label>
    <select name="switch" id="switch" data-role="slider">
      <option value="on">On</option>
      <option value="off">Off</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

but it doesn't seem to be work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _it doesn't seem to be work_. What does it do exactly? can you provide us with a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V67kF/

Comment: toggle works absolutely fine in your fiddle.. is there something you're expecting to see.

Comment: ya how to implement it in my rails app. where do I put the scrips?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the submit button, the action attribute must go to a valid page. ("demoform.asp") in form is just a simple demo page, which is not located on your computer/server.